# Error Loading Page. Unsupported URL

Tags: iphone

I am developing a mobile app and I am embedding an HTML page that references a phone number.

```
<a href="sms:xxxxxxxxxx" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Text 'i' to be Next</a>.
```

On an android there is no problem being able to text your message but on an iPhone I get an error message. "Error Loading Page. Unsupported URL"

Comment: Is there anything on the phone that could interfere, like a browser switcher etc? Your href looks correct (assuming it contains only numbers, +,-, and .)

Comment: I am not using any characters.